# `btrfs subvolume delete X` gives `ERROR: Could not statfs: Value too large for defined data type`

Tags: linux, btrfs

I play with btrfs in my arm(hf) NAS.

I successfully created a subvolume but now I am trying to delete it and get a system call error.

Any workarounds or better packages?

- To delete the subvolume.
- To create snapshots.

.

```
root@ODROID-HC2:/media/nas# btrfs subvolume list /media/nas
ID 318 gen 1216 top level 5 path 2023-03-13
root@ODROID-HC2:/media/nas# btrfs subvolume delete /media/nas/2023-03-13
ERROR: Could not statfs: Value too large for defined data type
root@ODROID-HC2:/media/nas# btrfs --version
btrfs-progs v5.10.1
root@ODROID-HC2:/media/nas# uname -a
Linux ODROID-HC2 4.14.294+ #1 SMP PREEMPT Sat Sep 24 10:24:15 UTC 2022 armv7l GNU/Linux
```